# Split div content at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to split an element after user clicks on it and the attr 'contenteditable' becomes 'true'. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/vaLz55fv/1/) fiddle works for the first paragraph but not second because the latter is in a p tag. Similary in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vaLz55fv/8/) fiddle you will see that when the element has html tags in it, the counter loses accuracy and hence the text before and after the cursor is not what you'd expect.

The assumption here is that the users will split the data in a way that the help tags will stay intact. As pointed out by dandavis here, e.g. the div has `<i>Hello</i> <b>Wo*rld</b>`, the user will only need to split the div into two divs, first will have `<i>Hello</i>` and the second div will have `<b>Wo*rld</b>` in it.

Html:

```
<div><mark>{DATE}</mark><i>via email: </i><mark><i>{EMAIL- BROKER OR TENANT}</i></mark></div>
```

JS:

```
var $splitbut = $('<p class="split-but">Split</p>');
$(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true').addClass('editing').append($splitbut);

var userSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
}
var start = userSelection.anchorOffset;
var end = userSelection.focusOffset;

var before = $(this).html().substr(0, start);
var after = $(this).html().substr(start, $(this).html().length);
```

The "Split" button is not working as generating the html is not an issue once I get proper "after" and "before" text. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Just for your information, the first fiddle's not working at all for me on Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: Just found out, I made the edit.

Comment: If you open the console, you will see the output.

Comment: you just want to know the text in the contentEditable before and after the cursor? i would clone it, inject a special char at the cursor position, split the whole on the special char. that sidesteps all the DOM complexity, which is a win imho.

Comment: I need to get the text before and after from the position where user clicks so that I can split the content into two divs.

Comment: you can't (validly) split into two divs if the user clicks inside a tag. how would you split `Hello <b>Wo*rld</b>` into two divs at the star? would you want to prepend `<b>` to the left of the right side? or throw away the `</b>` from the right side? or throw away all html tags and just keep the text? explain.

Comment: That's what the button is there for, this isn't the exact representation of the project as you may know, it is a simplified version of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, dandavis. This is part of a software solution for lawyers and the assumption in that the users won't have cases where the html tags would need to be split. As there is mostly <b> and <i> tags in the clauses/language/contracts etc that are mostly used to highlight, just like a word document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work for the specific case you describe

```
$('div, textarea').on('click', function(e) {
 var userSelection;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        userSelection = window.getSelection();
    }
    var start = userSelection.anchorOffset,
        end = userSelection.focusOffset,
        node = userSelection.anchorNode,
        allText = $(this).text(),
        nodeText = $(node).text();

// before and after inside node
  var nodeBefore = nodeText.substr(0, start);
  var nodeAfter = nodeText.substr(start, nodeText.length);

// before and after for whole of text
    var allExceptNode = allText.split(nodeText),
        before = allExceptNode[0] + nodeBefore,
        after = nodeAfter + allExceptNode[1];

  console.log('Before: ', before);
  console.log('------');
  console.log('After: ', after);

});
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vaLz55fv/10/

---

*It might exhibit issues if there are tags whose content is repeated in the whole text. (problem due to splitting)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.